# how to prevent a background from stretching ?

Tags: android, background

Good day guys

I am creating a game.At the moment, for my background , I use an image.
The problem is it stretches.How do I prevent that? because i can not add buttons on top of image-view

```
android:id="@+id/relatively"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/add"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
```

Comment: use scaleType if possible

Comment: because you are using `match_parent`, try to use `wrap_content`